# How to sort jQuery.dataTables by clicking on widget *outside* of the table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, datatables

**Long-winded introduction to the problem**

I have been asked to create a web application that displays a large amount of tabular data.  I've been asked to "freeze" the column headers.

I am well-aware of the fact that HTML does not support this and the various methods of freezing the table headers are like firing a pig out of a cannon and then saying that the pig is flying.

That being said, I found a neat project on GitHub called TableLock (https://github.com/kjellericson/TableLock) that has an example with both horizontal and vertical scrolling: http://kjell.haxx.se/tablelock/

Many solutions I've reviewed use the CSS position:fixed attribute, but this doesn't work for my project because it breaks horizontal scrolling.

TableLock makes a div with a copy of the contents of the table headers, positions it absolutely, and then moves it up and down the page as the user scrolls. (once again, like making a pig fly by firing it out of a cannon).  This seems to work, but it introduces a new problem:

**The problem**

By default, jQuery.dataTables allows the user to sort by clicking on the table-headers at the top of the table.  However, when using TableLock, the user cannot sort the table by clicking on these divs that appear in place of the column headers.  My question is: How can I program the page so that the user can click on these divs to sort the table?  Basically, I want it to be so that clicking on these faux header divs is the same as clicking on the actual table header.  How do I do this?

Comment: You could be interested in the floatThead-plugin: http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/datatables/ this is "fixing" table headers and it is working with datatables.

Comment: I hadn't heard of this one, and unlike 90% of these solutions, it looks like it even works with horizontal scrolling.  I'll look into it.

Comment: @NicoO, I found that jquery.floatThead works great for my project.  I will leave this question open in case someone else wants to answer the question I asked.